# How would I show that this limit exist? $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\Bigl(-2u^4-\frac{v^2}{t^2}+\frac{3u^2v}{t}\Bigr)^{\!1/4}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vectors

[image]

So, $f(0,0)=0$. Take $(u,v)$ as the unit vector along an arbitrary direction.

Then, Directional Derivative $\displaystyle =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f((0,0)+t(u,v))-f(0,0)}{t}$.

So, if $t^2u^2\leq tv \leq 2t^2u^2$, then I got that this limit is $$\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\Bigl(-2u^4-\frac{v^2}{t^2}+\frac{3u^2v}{t}\Bigr)^{\!1/4}.$$ But how would I show that this limit exist? I am stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach here may be geometrical. Let $E = \{x^2\le y\le 2x^2\}.$ Time to draw a picture. The boundary of $E$ consists of those two parabolas, and parabolas through the origin don't act like lines through the origin. In fact every line through $(0,0)$ will stay out of $E$ once you get close enough to $(0,0)$ (excluding $(0,0)$ itself of course).

Try it for the line $y=x$ for example. In the open first quadrant you will find this line is above the parabola $y=2x^2$ for $0<x<1/2.$ So we're out of $E,$ hence $f=0,$ on that part of the line. The directional derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction of this line thus has to be $0.$

The same kind of thing happens for all lines thru the origin. Therefore all directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ are $0.$

It follows that if $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0),$ then $Df(0,0)$ is the $0$ linear transformation. You want to show that can't hold. I'd look along the curve $y=(3/2)x^2$ to see why.